# Gscripts fetch large CSV

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets, urlfetch

This is probably easy, but I've been struggling. I am fetching a CSV and writing it to a google sheet. The CSV is updated daily and is recently too large for me to continue using ImportData. The code below from Max Mahkrov almost works, but the data is still too large for me to write in the sheet. How do I write a selection of the columns (say 1-8)?

Even better for me would to be to filter the rows based upon dates, but I see that there was an ArrayLib library that used to have that functionality and is now gone.

javascript:

```
function getBigCsv() {
  var url = 'https:URL.csv';
  var csv = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var data = Utilities.parseCsv(csv);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(2, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Limits Data to Date().valueOf() s greater than dtv. I'd probably use a custom dialog to select exactly how many days you wish to display.  But I don't want write that so I'll leave it up to you.

```
function getSmallerCsv() {
  const dt = new Date();
  const dtv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()).valueOf();
  var url = 'https:URL.csv';
  var csv = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var data = Utilities.parseCsv(csv);
  data = data.map(function(row){return [row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7]]}).filter(r => new Date(r[?]).valueOf() > dtv);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(2, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Cooper, this is really fantastic, thanks a lot. This totally relieves me of all space constraints and also, as a nice byproduct, the run time has gone from ~45 seconds to ~5 seconds.

Comment: You could use a dialog with a single select to pick the number of days to include in the data set. I used something like this to do something similar `function updateSelect2(){
        const v=[2,5,10,20,30];
        var id='sel2';
        var select = document.getElementById(id);
        select.options.length = 0; 
        for(var i=0;i<v.length;i++) {
          select.options[i] = new Option(v[i],v[i]);
        }
      }`

Answer (score 1):

### `Utilities.parseCsv` returns you a 2D array that you can filter e.g. with [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Sample:

```js
function getBigCsv() {
  var url = 'https:URL.csv';
  var csv = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var data = Utilities.parseCsv(csv);
  data = data.map(function(row){return [row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7]]});
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(2, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @ziganotschka. That is not the solution I would have guessed, but it works perfectly, and I think I can use something similar to build in a row filter as well. In case you are interested, I'm using Google Sheets to power a vaccine timeline website here: [vaxtimer.com](https://vaxtimer.com) Thanks again.